# axis2: content length must be specified

Tags: java, apache-axis, webservice-client

I am writing a SOAP service client using axis2. I generated the client code with wsdl2java, then I try to

```
Request req = new Request();
req.setParameter("XXX");

ServiceStub stub = new ServiceStub();                                     
stub.remoteService(req);
```

At runtime, I get an `AxisFault`: `Content length must be specified`

Any idea of what's going wrong or how to specify content length?

Comment: Can you provide a little more description on the type of service you are trying to connect to and also the code itself

Comment: @Gigaquad: question edited. It's a SOAP service, the stub was generated by wsdl2java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Axis2 will include the content-length value in the HTTP header if you disable the chunking by default

As per the [XML RPC specifications](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html):

> ### Header requirements
>
> The format of the URI in the first line of the header is not specified. For example, it could be empty, a single slash, if the server is only handling XML-RPC calls. However, if the server is handling a mix of incoming HTTP requests, we allow the URI to help route the request to the code that handles XML-RPC requests. (In the example, the URI is /RPC2, telling the server to route the request to the "RPC2" responder.)
>
> A User-Agent and Host must be specified.
>
> The Content-Type is text/xml.
>
> **The Content-Length must be specified and must be correct**.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I finally got it. According to [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-user@ws.apache.org/msg23935.html) it's a long-known issue of axis.

Using axis2, I added the following to the my service stub

```
_operationClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);
```

and it worked fine!